# Adding markers on the map - OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When I add vectors they share the same text from the last car.position value. I want to have text for each marker.  Example logs from console.log(position.car): example.js:72 1740, example.js:72 1653. How to fix this code?

```
  const addMarkers = (lat, long) => {
    if(lat && lat !== 0) {
        const point = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat, long], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));
        const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: point
        });
        vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
      }
    }
    //
    positions.forEach(position => {
      let long = position.geolocation.longitude;
      let lat = position.geolocation.latitude;
      const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: vectorStyle
      })
      if (long !== 0 && long !== 999.9 && long !== "" &&  long !== undefined) {
        addMarkers(long, lat);  
      }
      vectorLayer.setZIndex(5);
      map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    });
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you expect to happen and what happes instead

Comment: @MechMK1 I expect to have all markers with the text of each position.car value. Instead, I have all markers with a text of the last position.car value

Comment: Then please edit your question to reflect this information better. The more relevant information a question contains, the more likely someone can answer it.

Comment: MechMK1 Thank you for advice!